# Java String Timestamp Conversion to 12 Hour AM/PM With Correct Time

Tags: java, timestamp, timezone, datetime-format, zoneddatetime

I have a string timestamp like the following, `2021-06-22T21:54:18.496Z`, I am trying to convert this into a 12 hour am/pm. I've tried the following:

```
String myTime = "2021-06-22T21:54:18.496Z";
var zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(myTime).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm a"));
System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
```

The output appears correct `June 22, 2021 9:54 PM` but the time is incorrect. I'm thinking I need to get and set the correct time zone first before the parse but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: And what output do you expect?

Comment: What did your search turn up? I would suppose that you could find quite a lot about similar conversions on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
I edited the answer to show how to use your JVM's current default time zone, and a specific time zone.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myTime = "2021-06-22T21:54:18.496Z";
    parseFormatAndPrintWithSpecificTimeZone(myTime);
    parseFormatAndPrintUsingDefaultTimeZone(myTime);
}

private static void parseFormatAndPrintUsingDefaultTimeZone(String myTime) {
    var zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(myTime)
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss.SSS a").withZone(
                    ZoneId.systemDefault() // Get the JVM’s current default time zone. Can change at any moment during runtime. If important, confirm with the user.x
                    ));
    System.out.println("Time using my JVM current default time zone:"+ zonedDateTime);
    
}

private static void parseFormatAndPrintWithSpecificTimeZone(String myTime) {

    var zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(myTime)
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss.SSS a").withZone(
                    ZoneId.of("Asia/Singapore") //Specified TimeZone
                    ));
    System.out.println("Time using specific timezone (singapore in this case):"+zonedDateTime);
    
}
```

Comment: What if you don't know the time zone to supply to `withZone()`, is there a way to determine the correct time zone base on the string?

Comment: @JosephFreeman, Z at the end of the string means Zulu/UTC. Have you tried to use your jvm's default time zone? Try using Zoneid.systemDefault(). Please let me know if it still fails.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Substitute your desired [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html), [`FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html), &  [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html).

```java
Instant
.parse( "2021-06-22T21:54:18.496Z" )
.atZone(
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/Istanbul" )             // Or ZoneId.systemDefault()
)
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ) 
    .withLocale( Locale.FRANCE )               // Or Locale.getDefault()
)
```

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/ideone/Index/submit/).

Notice the different date and time-of-day, but still representing same moment, the same point on the timeline.

> mercredi 23 juin 2021 à 00:54:18 Heure d'Europe de l'Est

## Details

While the [Answer by N.M.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68200111/642706) is correct, I suggest a slightly different approach.

Your input string `2021-06-22T21:54:18.496Z` is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The `T` separates the date portion from the time-of-day portion. The `Z` on the end means an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. The `Z` is pronounced “Zulu”, for “Zulu time”.

The appropriate type for this specific kind of string of [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). No need to specify a formatting pattern, as the *java.time* classes by default use ISO 8601 formats when parsing/generating text.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2021-06-22T21:54:18.496Z" ) ;
```

An `Instant` represents a moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), always in UTC, meaning an offset of zero.

Note that your input, and an `Instant`, use an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) but lack a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone). A time zone is named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. A [real time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) uses a format of `Continent/Region`.

If you want to adjust from an offset of zero to a particular time zone, specify a [`ZoneID`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) to produce a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

You may choose to specify a format when generating text to represent the value within our `ZonedDateTime` object. But I suggest soft-coding, to let *java.time* automatically localize. Specify a `Locale` to determine localization issues.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale(locale ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

Comment: This explanation was actually quote helpful!! Thank you!!